# IIS DNS not defaulting to Index.html

Tags: html, iis

So I'll be honest, I'm 100% utterly new to IIS.

My issue is that when ever I enter in my domain name (www.something.com for example) it does not go to the index.html page unless I actaully type in www.something.com/index.html

I have tried using URL Rewrites to make it so that if www.something.com is type in, it would bring the user to www.something.com/index.html, but that didn't work, nor did having index.html at the top of the Default Document list.

I even tried using the HTTP Redirect service but that just resulted in a redirect loop...

If there's any additional information I need to provide to help solve this issue, do let me know.

Thanks for your time

EDIT:

Here's what the Default Document list looks like:

```
<defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

Handlers:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: No need for Url Rewriting and it has nothing to do with DNS. Look for "Default Documents" in your website settings panel.

Comment: Sorry for all those removed comments earlier, I kept making typos

Comment: Did you make sure your `Web.Config` is affecting anything at all?

Comment: I removed the Web.Config file to see if it did. Everything else broke after that. Not sure if that's the best way to test that.

Comment: Show the `<handlers>` and `<modules>` sections in your `Web.Config`

Comment: Handlers added, but there wasn't any <modules> in the config file